# Definition: limit of a sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition

What is the purpose not to choose $|x_n-a|\leq\epsilon$ instead of $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ in the definition of convergence? Is their a substancial difference (or a practical one)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no there is not substantial difference. There is only practical difference in the sense that you get something that is indeed less than and not less or equal to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$ implies $|x_n-a|\leqslant\varepsilon$. To see it conversely, note the condition "for *all* $\varepsilon>0$". Thus, since the statement "for all $\varepsilon>0$ ...  $|x_n-a|\leqslant\varepsilon$" holds for arbitrary $\varepsilon$, it holds also when we replace $\varepsilon$ by $\varepsilon/2$ throughout. That is, "for all $\varepsilon/2>0$ (i.e. for all $\varepsilon>0$), there is an integer $m$ such that $|x_n-a|\leqslant\varepsilon/2$ whenever $n>m$"; and from this it follows that "for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integer $m$ such that $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n>m$". The reason for preferring $<$ to $\leqslant$ is simplicity and ease of application.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. It is easy to prove that the statement

- For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ so that for each $n>N$, $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$

is equivalent to the statement

- For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ so that for each $n>N$, $|x_n-a|\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: And why have the stronger statement then?

Comment: It isn't stronger, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the main point of using open definitions $(\lt)$ rather than closed ones $(\le)$ is because similar definitions arise in dealing with continuity, and this is a concept naturally generalised to topological spaces via open sets.

So some people would want to use open definitions rather than closed ones for pedagogical reasons - because that avoids confusion later, and one simply uses open definitions for everything.

Comment: And maybe because the symbol $<$ is shorter to write than $\leq$. :D